# Magento Cron Job Error - Invalid Callback

Tags: php, xml, magento

Im having some issues getting a cron job to work within Magentos cron system.

My module folder structure is as follows:

/app/code/local/Nnn/AbandonedCartEmails/etc/config.xml
/app/code/local/Nnn/AbandonedCartEmails/Model/Observer.php

My config xml is as follows:

```
<config> 

<!-- 
    The module's node contains basic 
    information about each Magento module
-->
<modules>
    <!--
        This must exactly match the namespace and module's folder
        names, with directory separators replaced by underscores
    -->
    <Nnn_AbandonedCartEmails>

        <!-- The version of our module, starting at 0.0.1 -->
        <version>0.0.1</version>

    </Nnn_AbandonedCartEmails>
</modules>

<global>
    <!-- Defining models -->
    <models>

        <!--
            Unique identifier in the model's node.
            By convention, we put the module's name in lowercase.
        -->
        <nnn_abandonedcartemails>

            <!--
                The path to our models directory, with directory
                separators replaced by underscores
            -->
            <class>Nnn_AbandonedCartEmails_Model</class>

        </nnn_abandonedcartemails>

    </models>
</global>

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <nnn_abandonedcartemails>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>abandonedcartemails/observer::processEmails</model>
            </run>
        </nnn_abandonedcartemails>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

My observer class looks like this:

```
class Nnn_AbandonedCartEmails_Model_Observer 
{
    public function processEmails()
    {

         /***/
```

So the cron job is registering and is added to the cron_schedule table, however whenever it attempts to execute it produces and error along the lines of

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback: abandonedcartemails/observer::processEmails does not exist' in /pathtosite/www/app/Mage.php:594
```

So it looks like I have a config issue, but I cant seem to see where the problem lies. The namespacing and naming conventions in Magento's xml files are quite frustrating to work with, so hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can see where I have made the mistake.

Any help always appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.


Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model name is wrong.

In `<model>` tag, write `<abandonedcartemails>` instead of `<nnn_abandonedcartemails>`.

Your model is not calling. That is why this is error